# if else query in mysql

Tags: mysql

i need an example of nested if-else condition in mysql query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could also use case statements for if-else conditions

```
SELECT
  (CASE field1
    WHEN 'A' THEN 'value is A'
    WHEN 'B' THEN 'value is B'
    ELSE 'value is neither A or B'
  END)
FROM your_table;
```

or

```
SELECT
  (CASE
    WHEN (field1 IS NULL) THEN 'value is NULL'
    WHEN (field1 = 1) THEN 'value is 1'
    ELSE 'value is neither NULL or 1'
  END)
FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 4):

You mean the IF(*expr*, *expr*, *expr*) *function* as [defined here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html)?  An example would be:

```
SELECT
  name, ID,
  IF(category = 'fulltime', 1, 
    IF(category = 'parttime', loading, 0)) AS equivloading
FROM
  person
```