# optimizing mysql if - else depend on my case

Tags: mysql, logic

I'm very newbie in mysql. pardon me if i just ask a newbie question here.

in my case, I want to make branching in mysql like this :

1. if office_id is not null then is_invited = 1
2. else if office_id = '0000' then is_invited = 1
3. else is_invited = 0

after I saw @thomasrutter answer here " [if else query in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059136/if-else-query-in-mysql/3059184#3059184) "..
I made query like this on mysql :

```
select IF(y.office_id IS NOT NULL, 1, IF(y.office_id = '0000', 1, IF(y.office_id IS NULL, 0, 1))) as is_invited
```

my question is,, can I make the query to be more optimize (with respect to performance)

many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic doesn't make sense here.

Case 2 is always satisfied/never reached. If office_id is not null, then you already assign is_invited = 1. So office_id = '0000' will never be tested, since it's always not null. Really, your logic should simply be `IF(y.office_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) as is_invited`

Comment: ya, before i just make IFNULL(y.office_id,0) as is_invited.. but i dont know why, the ofice_id = '0000' are known as NULL so I need to make sure that '0000' actually is not null :)

Comment: ohh yess,, we can just make IF(y.office_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) as is_invited.. its work although for y.office_id = '0000'.. hehehehe.. i'm sorry,,but really,. before, I try using ifnull() and '0000' is defined as NULL so i just want to make sure that '0000' actualy is not null.. thanks @Derek Kromm